# Thread executes after exception also (During Debugging)

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm trying to add some values to an ArrayList in one thread and remove from another thread without using any lock or mutex. While removing an `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown and removeThread should stop there only, but it doens't! Why?`

Please look at following code:

```
class Program
{
    static ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        Thread removeThread = new Thread(p.StartRemoval);
        Thread addThread = new Thread(p.StartAddition);
        addThread.Start();
        removeThread.Start();

        addThread .Join();
        removeThread.Join();

        //Console.ReadKey();
    }

    void StartRemoval()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            alist.Remove(i); // Exception
    }

    void StartAddition()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            alist.Add(i); 
    }
}
```

Even after exception in `removeThread`, it executes for remaining iterations. Can you please explain why?

Stack Trace:

`at System.Collections.ArrayList.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.StartRemoval() in Program.cs:line 34
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()`

in following scenerio, i'm getting above stack trace

1. put breakpoint to last curly brace of all the methods. (main, StartAddition, StartRemoval)
2. Start debugging.
3. StartRemoval executes the last line even after exception.

If you run it without debugging it's working as expected and correctly. But the stack trace is same. `Remove` is called in code but `RemoveAt` is traced in trace report.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your question - explain what you're seeing. I suspect you're mistaken in your diagnostics.

Comment: Do you mean t2 keeps running? t1 will end when it throws an uncaught exception.

Comment: Whatever Thread1 appears to be doing is irrelevant. You are using an ArrayList in a non-Threadsafe manner.

Comment: @Jon: I tried to execute it many times but same behaviour.
@Russell: No same thread keeps running even after exception.
@Heandel: it doesn't.
@Henk: Yes, but thread should stop after unhandeled exception irrespective of whether it was executing thread safe code or not.

Comment: @Azodious: You still haven't explained what you're seeing... why you believe it's keeping going. It would also help if you'd say what version of .NET you're using.

Comment: @Jon: if you add Console.WriteLine as last line of `StartRemoval` and `StartAddition` methods. both lines are printed. Target Framework is 3.5

Comment: @Azodious: I've just run the program, and there's no indication that an exception is ever thrown.

Comment: -1: Supposed repro program doesn't reproduce the problem, and the stack trace shown clearly isn't from the repro program.

Comment: @Jon: Thats's the trace report i'm getting in visual studio 2008. and if i use RemoveAt method, ArgumentOutOfRangeException is received and thread stops. but if you change the start order of threads then on 2nd occurance of exception, removeThread stops.

Comment: @Azodious: Well, I can run the code you've given with no exceptions. It's not guaranteed to be exception-free of course, as it's not thread-safe... but if the exception is there and uncaught, execution won't continue. Where are you even seeing the stack trace? Perhaps it's something that's caught internally?

Comment: @Heandel,Jon: i've updated the original post with 3 steps. if you follow these steps i'm sure you also will see this strange behavior. i've tried same code on several machines and the thread executes even after exception is thrown. (only during debugging environment)

Comment: I know there is something wrong with stack trace but on every machine same trace is produced.

Comment: @Heandel: Ahhh ... so now i can relax a bit. well, looking for someone from Microsoft who has developed Visual Studio debugger to throw some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't throw an exception [ArrayList.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.remove.aspx) just throws [NotSupportedException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx) and just when

```
The ArrayList is read-only.

-or-

The ArrayList has a fixed size.
```

See MSDN link for detail, your current code doesn't do anything to throw an exception.

Comment: No, ` alist.Remove(i);` is throwing `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Azodious, from .Net 1.1 upto now it just throws a NotSupportedException may be you are talking about another language not C#? see MSDN link above. you can try it simply out of thread, remove from list without any item.

Comment: @Azodious: What makes you think it's throwing an exception?

Comment: @Saeed: If you don't believe me. pls try to run it on your machine.

Comment: @Azodious: I have. There was no evidence of an exception. If you change the `Remove` call to `RemoveAt` *then* it throws an exception.

Comment: @Jon: pls see the stack trace in original post.

Comment: @Azodious: I suggest *you* look at the stack trace. Note how it includes a call to RemoveAt, not Remove?

Comment: @Jon: yes, even if src contains call to Remove, trace report has RemoveAt as stack top. that's strange and probably remove calls RemoveAt internally. but whatever it is ... that's the stack trace i'm getting.

Comment: @Azodious: Given that I can't reproduce this and the stack trace looks incorrect, it's hard to see how we can really move forward...

Comment: @Jon: yup i understand. let me look more into it but i guess that by the time i reach some conclusion, this questions might have been closed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are seeing with the exception during debugging is probably the result of the code being out of sync with the binaries. I see this from time to time. It does not happen very often, but I suspect many of us have seen at least once or twice over the years. The solution that usually works to is to select Rebuild Solution from the Build menu item.

Also, note that the behavior of this code will be unpredictable in general because you are accessing an object (namely an instance of `ArrayList`) from more than one thread when the documentation states that instances of this type are not thread-safe.

Comment: I've posted it here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/667063/bug-in-debugger-thread-executes-after-strange-exception#details

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to arise from the fact that thread t1 is dependent on thread t2 but not visa versa.  Thread t2 can happily add elements to the end of your array list without worrying what is within the container (so long as the ArrayList has been properly allocated like you have done).

Thread t1 however is dependent on what thread t2 does.  Say for example thread t1 wants to remove element 5 from alist, its possible thread t2 is still adding '5' and it doesn't yet exist within alist, this then causes an exception.  t1 then throws this exception and finishes execution.  Because t2 is independent of t1 (as described above) it carries on its execution until all elements have been added.

I believe the following would get around this issue:

```
t2.Start();    // Start t2 thread
t2.Join();     // Wait for thread t2 to add all elements to alist

t1.Start();    // Start t1 thread knowing all elements in alist have been added
t1.Join();     // Wait for thread t1 to complete execution
```

If you could put a try catch arround the exception in StartT1 and post us the exact exception you're getting this might help narrow down exactly whats going on, but I think the above is most likely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Azodious described above would probably throw an IndexOutOfRangeException, i.e. the element you're removing doesn't exist

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what is happening. but i don't want to resolve this issue but want to know why that thread is not stopped.

if you remove the join statements and add `Console.WriteLine` after each `for`. both lines are printed.

Comment: @Azodious this has got me stumped, looking at the description in [Exceptions](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpExceptionHandling.aspx) it says any unhandled exceptions will cause the program to terminate.  I've tried out your code and the best I can get is a console.WriteLine after removethread has finished execution.  Do both WriteLines print for you each and every time you run the application?